# Optimización de código para disminuir tiempo de ejecución

Tags: java

**Problema:**

Dados 3 números a, b y c. Contar cuántos números en el intervalo `[a,b]` tienen exactamente `c` bits encendidos.

```
Entrada de prueba
5 --número de casos a evaluar
1 10 1
1 10 2
1 10 3
1 98305 3
41249 60398 12
Salida de prueba
4
5
1
666
666
```

La entrada se lee desde un archivo de texto y el resultado se escribe en un archivo de texto.

El programa está terminado pero no sé de qué forma podría ejecutarse más rápido.

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.*;
    import static java.lang.Integer.bitCount;
    
    class Test {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    
            File f = new File("data.in");
            Scanner s = new Scanner(f);
    
            f = new File("data.out");
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);
    
            
            int cases = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
    
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    
            while (cases-- >= 1) {
                String[] abc = s.nextLine().split(" ");
    
                int a = Integer.parseInt(abc[0]);
                int b = Integer.parseInt(abc[1]);
                int c = Integer.parseInt(abc[2]);
    
                int counter = 0;
    
                for (int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
                    if (bitCount(i) == c) counter++;
                }
    
                builder.append(counter).append("\n");
    
            }
            fw.write(builder.toString());
            fw.close();
    
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En lugar de recorrer el intervalo y probar uno por uno contando bits, podrías hacerlo por medio de cálculos de combinaciones. Sería algo así:

```
a = mínimo
b = máximo
c = bits encendidos
resultado = (combinaciones de c en b) - (combinaciones de c en (a - 1))
```

Dicho lo anterior puedes usar la fórmula de combinaciones:

[image: Fórmula de combinaciones]

Se traduciría en lo siguiente:

```
private static long factorial(int number) {
    if (number <= 1)
        return 1;

    return number * factorial(number - 1);
}

private static int combinations(int n, int r) {
    if (n == r)
        return 1;

    if (n == 0)
        return 0;

    return (int) (factorial(n) / (factorial(n - r) * factorial(r)));
}
```

Para encontrar las combinaciones primero necesitas saber cuántos bits se necesitan para expresar un número específico. Para ello puedes crear un método que lo haga:

```
private static int countBitsRequired(int number) {
    if (number == 0)
        return 0;

    return (int)(Math.log(number) / Math.log(2) + 1);
}
```

Para encontrar el número de combinaciones de `c` bits encendidos dentro de `n` bits entonces lo puedes hacer de manera recursiva omitiendo el bit más significativo y encontrando el total de combinaciones dentro de los bits restantes. Luego a ese resultado le sumas el número de combinaciones de `c-1` bits dentro del número de bits que representan el `número original - el valor del bit más significativo`. La explicación es un poco confusa, pero tal vez con el siguiente código lo puedas entender mejor:

```
private static int findCombinationsOfBitsOn(int number, int bitsOn) {
    int bitsRequired = countBitsRequired(number);

    if (bitsOn < 0 || bitsRequired < bitsOn)
        return 0;

    int mostSignificantBitValue = (int) Math.pow(2, bitsRequired - 1);

    return combinations(bitsRequired - 1, bitsOn) + findCombinationsOfBitsOn(number - mostSignificantBitValue, bitsOn - 1);
}
```

Con respecto al tiempo de ejecución, probando las entradas y salidas de prueba que pusiste, hice una comparación entre las dos maneras y con una sola ejecución la diferencia es mínima, pero si lo haces dentro de un ciclo para que repita cada una 10000 veces por ejemplo, la diferencia se incrementa bastante y hacerlo por cálculo resulta más rápido que hacerlo contando bits número por número.

Answer (score 0):

Sin duda alguna puedes optimizar `bitCount()` para que *sabiendo el limite de bits*, no cuente mas allá de dicho límite.

Comment: Ya está optimizada, es parte del JDK.

Comment: Si no sabe cuantos bits es tu limite, la función va a contar _todos_ los 1s que haya.... si tu limite es 4 y le pasas un número de 60 bits, la función va a ver todos los 60 1s.... pero luego del 4o 1, podrías _parar_.